# Difference between New York strip and a first cut strip

Tags: steak, cut-of-meat

What is the difference between a New York strip and a first cut strip steak?

Answer (score 1):

From [Huffington Post](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/steven-raichlen/5-great-steaks-to-remembe_b_3768984.html):

> Strip steak: The multiplicity of names — New York strip, club steak, Kansas City steak, shell steak — attests to the popularity of this steak. Tender (but not too tender); well-marbled (i.e., generously endowed with fat); and richly flavored — what more could you ask for in a steak? Not that you asked, but a center cut New York strip is Steven Raichlen’s favorite cut. **Tip: Sometimes you’ll find supermarket strip steaks labeled “first cut.” This makes them sound more exclusive, but actually the “first cut” has a visible line of gristle running through the meat. That’s why “first cut” strips cost about half the price of the more desirable center cuts of the short loin.**

(Emphasis mine.)